# BAT file - open popup

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've written a little .bat file containing the following commands:

```
@echo off
Slmgr /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
slmgr /ato edkk4b-3sf6-j3h4-i5i5-d04gd453dgr3
```

Then i've packaged it in a .exe with a tool.
It works great but at the end of the execution two popup are displayed...
Can i remove the first popup and let display only the second?

Comment: You'd have to edit the slmgr.vbs file to do that.

Comment: i can't do that for every pc in which the file .exe(or .bat) will run...

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, there are 2 options:

1. Run slmgr with cscript so all of the output goes to the console.

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal
   cscript //nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
   cscript //nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato edkk4b-3sf6-j3h4-i5i5-d04gd453dgr3

   Call :MsgBox "Done!" "VBOkOnly" "Process Complete"
   exit /b

   :MsgBox prompt type title
   ::Function by MC ND
   setlocal enableextensions
   set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%vbs.tmp"
   >"%tempFile%" echo(WScript.Quit msgBox("%~1",%~2,"%~3") & cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%tempFile%"
   set "exitCode=%errorlevel%" & del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
   endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
   ```
2. Edit 1 copy of slmgr.vbs and put it on a network share and run it from there for all PC's.

Comment: Matt, i like the idea the output goes to the console. Is there a command that i can insert in the bat file after the two main commands that open a popup such as "Done" at the end?

Comment: Yes, that's easy to do with a little vbscript.